# checkboxes in recyclerview get changed automatically by scrolling in android

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> hashMapArrayList;

public void onBindViewHolder(final EChallanRecyclerCardViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {


 holder.cbSelectedchallans.setChecked(false);





        holder.cbSelectedchallans.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {
                    String cvTotChallanPayAmount= holder.tvChallanPayAmount.getText().toString().replace("₹","");
                    int TotChallanPayAmount=Integer.parseInt(cvTotChallanPayAmount);
                    TotaltoPay=TotaltoPay+TotChallanPayAmount;
                    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("TotaltoPay",TotaltoPay);
                    Intent intent = new Intent("Add_Send_TotaltoPay");
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(cntx).sendBroadcast(intent);



                } else {
                    if(TotaltoPay!=0) {
                        String cvTotChallanPayAmount = holder.tvChallanPayAmount.getText().toString().replace("₹", "");
                        int TotChallanPayAmount = Integer.parseInt(cvTotChallanPayAmount);
                        TotaltoPay = TotaltoPay - TotChallanPayAmount;
                        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                        bundle.putInt("TotaltoPay",TotaltoPay);
                        Intent intent = new Intent("Remove_Send_TotaltoPay");
                        intent.putExtras(bundle);
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(cntx).sendBroadcast(intent);

                    }
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Adapter class add `dataObjectHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);` in `DataObjectHolder`

Example code

```
@Override
public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.content_my_leaves, parent, false);

    DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);
    dataObjectHolder.setIsRecyclable(false); // this line you should add
    return dataObjectHolder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Use like this adpter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ModelClass> {

    private final ArrayList<ModelClass> list;
    private final Activity context;

    public MyAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<ModelClass> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.raw_project_add, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.raw_project_add, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkboxProject);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                    list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.chkboxProject, viewHolder.checkbox);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position); // This line is important.

        viewHolder.checkbox.setText(list.get(position).getTitle());
        viewHolder.checkbox.setTypeface(Utils.getTypeFace(context));
        viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());

        return convertView;
    }
    }
```

implement AdapterView.OnItemClickListener in your class.

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) v.getTag(R.id.chkboxProject);
//        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), isCheckedOrNot(checkbox), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private String isCheckedOrNot(CheckBox checkbox) {
    if (checkbox.isChecked())
        return "is checked";
    else
        return "is not checked";
    }
```

Comment: how to write  list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); for my Arraylist of Hashmap like ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> hashMapArrayList;

Comment: a list is your array list I have mentioned in below class declaration.
I think u want to use hashMapArrayList.get(..)......
if it's not resolved then you will be using ArrayList.

Comment: i  hav issue with the checkboxes getting unchecked when scrolling the recyclerview

Comment: I have use listview and it's worked nicely. can you try it for replacing listview to recycler view?